# Names for automatic machines' programs

Tags: phrase-requests

A machine can be programmed, and different programs can be chosen for different tasks. One such task may be to initialise the machine, while the main purpose of the machine is to manufacture something. Could such a program, that causes the machine to process/manufacture something be called a "work program" or "working program"? What other scenarios / classifications of programs can you think of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The terminology I'm familiar with is that housekeeping programs (boot, reset, shutdown) are called *routines* and mechanical processing instructions are either called *jobs* or simply *programs*. That may be specific to the CNC (Computer Numerical Controlled tools) world, but it seemed to be universal in the shops I've worked in.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of work, how about a word that has a clearer (more restricted) meaning, like **production program**, or **manufacturing program**, or **building program**?